# Non Blocking UI with Gmail Api in Winrt

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, gmail-api, winrt-async

I am developing an gmail client in uwp and want to use gmail api but the want the get messages asynchronous wihout blocking the ui the following method blocks the ui.

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> GetMessagesAsync(string userId, string labelId, long maxResults)
    {
        await AuthenticateAsync();
        List<Message> result = new List<Message>();
        UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
        request.LabelIds = labelId;
        request.MaxResults = maxResults;

        try
        {
            ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
            result.AddRange(response.Messages);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Task.Run` for non blocking

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> GetMessagesAsync(string userId, string labelId, long maxResults)
            {
                await AuthenticateAsync();
              return  await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    List<Message> result = new List<Message>();
                    UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
                    request.LabelIds = labelId;
                    request.MaxResults = maxResults;

                    try
                    {
                        ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
                        result.AddRange(response.Messages);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    }

                    return result;
                });



       }
```